# Difference between View Composer and Helper in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I don't know if same question asked or not. but can any one explain difference between these 2 Laravel feature ? & Which one to use and when ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of Laravel, a **[Helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers)** is a global function you can use to perform specific operations on arrays, strings, etc. For example, let's say, you need to slugify a string:

```
$title = str_slug('Laravel 5 Framework', '-');

// laravel-5-framework
```

-- easily done with the `str_slug()` helper (function).

**[View composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers)**, on the other hand...

> ...are callbacks or class methods that are called when a view is
>   rendered. If you have data that you want to be bound to a view each
>   time that view is rendered, a view composer can help you organize that
>   logic into a single location.

In other words, they are not simple functions, but the framework's construct used when you need to make sure that a variable (resource) is available across multiple views.

For example, the code below will make sure that **every time** the `sidebar.blade.php` view is rendered, it will have access to the `$navigation` variable:

```
// Using Closure, within a Service Provider...

View::composer('sidebar', function ($view) {
    $navigation = array(/*...*/);
    $view->with('navigation', $navigation);
});
```

This means you've just centralized the navigation source, as opposed to passing the navigation items from each controller that handles a page with the sidebar.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.